# Copy row values on unique identifiers based in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have pandas dataframe in following format.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Value in `Date Field 1` could either be `Null` or `some date value` (which is appended every day). What I want is whenever for specific combination of `ID1` and `ID2`, `Date Field 1` is `not Null`, I want that value to be copied to other rows also as follows:

[image]

How do I do it efficiently as dataframe is very large? it is possible for the given combination of `ID1` and `ID2`, `actual date value` could be followed by `null` and vice-versa.

Comment: `df['Date Field1'] = df.groupby(['ID1','ID2'])['Date Field 1'].bfill()`

Comment: Why `.bfill?`. What if `nan` values and `date` values are mixed for the given `ID1` and `ID2` combination? My point is it is possible for the given combination of `ID1` and `ID2`, `actual date value` could be followed by `null` and vice-versa. this solution might not work for all the cases.

Comment: Then use `.transform('first')` instead of `bfill()`. Without *all cases* in sample data, hard to tell.